# Aligning C Code using a shell script

Tags: shell

A different Question is up.

Assume I have the following code base. 
Existing code is as follows.

```
int main() { 
/*Commented Added by abc
    int abc; */
/* Code Added by abc */
    int def; 
}
```

I would like the new code to be as follows.

```
int main() { 
    /*Commented by abc
    int abc; */
    /* Added by abc */
    int def; 
}
```

---

There is no actual code change is being done in the above example. However the comments are alligned correctly, based on the new code added. I.e. i searched for the new line of code being added by ABC and alligned the previous couple of lines according to this line allignment.

Now, i am working on huge code base, and it is almost impossible to make such code changes manually. please advice on how this could be attained in the possible simplest way.

Comment: Possibly see:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609805/code-formatter-beautifier-for-c-on-linux-for-emacs-user answers cover other platforms eg http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/

Comment: There are tools that do this; they are not shell scripts but major C programs that understand an awful lot of C syntax.   You've had `indent` mentioned; it is but one of many.  `astyle` is another; `uncrustify` is another; `cb` (C Beautifier) is the original (7th Edition UNIX™) program of this ilk, but you'll be hard-pressed to find it and probably wouldn't want it if you did.  Note that `vim` can often be used (the `=` command).  Also, changes are best not kept in the source code but in the version control system you're using — you are using one, aren't you?

Comment: The correct thing to do here is to delete the comments and use a VCS.

Answer (score 0):

How about this crude way:

```
VIMINIT='call feedkeys("gg=G:wq\<CR>")' vi myFile.c
```

Answer (score 0):

[GNU Indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) can transform C files to a unified style, and it comes with many options - some of which relates to placing of comments.